# AngularJS - ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide behave crazy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It seems like AngularJS is reacting crazy on the following scenario:

When I provide to a route from another Controller, everything acts right and the template is shown right. But after reloading the same route (!) in the browser the template is behaving crazy because ng-if and ng-show/ ng-hide blocks are not acting right. The template relates on search()-variables from the URL (got via AngularJS).

What could be the problem?

In my controller:

```
$scope.excel = $location.search().excel;
```

I checked this via console.log(), it is false. But my template does not act right, I tired everything from `=== true` to `= true` and all that stuff.

```
<div class="row" ng-hide="loading" ng-show="!excel && !tooMuchData">
```

Comment: Please provide some code, is hard to understand what s happening there

Comment: Why do you need `ng-hide` and an `ng-show` on the same element?

Comment: Don't use ng-hide and ng-show on the same element. Choose one or the other. For example, `ng-show="!loading && !excel && !tooMuchData"`

Answer (score 0):

It's beneficial to provide us with accompanying code and / or Plunker to showcase your problem.

Here I am gonna guess based on sparse information you provided:

Somehow state of the controller for that view is influenced with from what state you came from or the fact something has been passed to the controller when coming into that state.

Here is a couple of examples how this might happen:

1. Something was passed to the controller when you changed states. Let's say you list your porn videos in categories and you list them (/porn). When you select a certain category (eg. MILF) you open a new view (enter a new state and pass the id of that category). Now the route is /porn/MILF Then you list the videos. All videos in this section are now from the category with Id you passed from the previous state via router. When you refresh that Id becomes unknown and when filter unknown from data ut can get funky if you have not set defaults.
2. Your controller depends on some property in $rootScope that is reset upon refresh. Same example as above but somewhere upon picking a category you said.

> $rootScope.pickedCategory = 'MILF'

You now try to do stuff in your controller with it but it's now unknown. You should generally stop abusing rootScope like this.

**EDIT: now that you provided the code ng-show and ng-hide in on the same object is a terrible idea and probably the cause of problems.**

Use either of those not both on the same element.

You can always use this rule for conditions:

condition you wanna to be true - A and condition you wanna to be false - B

equals to:

condition you wanna to be true A && !B

or

condition you wanna to be false B && !A

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using both `ng-hide` and `ng-show` on the same div. ng-hide is the inverse of ng-show and vice versa. Both does is setting `display: none` and `display: block`. Also no mention about your `loading` parameter.

Just only use `ng-show` with `!loading`.
Ex: `ng-show= "!excel && !tooMuchData && !loading"`

Comment: Talking about ng-if, ng-show and ng-hide didn't mean that I use them at the same DOM element!